# how to allow pass through in express handlers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, middleware

I have an`POST` api endpoint lets say `/users` to fetch the list of users.

It is `POST` because body of the request is very huge and might not fit in url for `GET` request.

suppose the body of user `POST` have a key called `age` , which should give me user of certain age ie kind of filtering

now in express i have route like

```
app.post('/users', function(r,res){
  // function body
})
```

and i cant actually put any code inside that function body

so i was able to intercept the request by using one more handler for `/users` and putting it before the original handler but obviously it intercepts all `/users` requests and breaks earlier functionality

how can i intercept only the request with particular age and then pass through other requests to the original handler, so that original functionality keeps working?

I want to know how can i do this using route handlers and not middlewares ?

i cant mess with the url or request body also

Comment: I don't understand... why can't you put code in that function? And why do you have another route for the same path/method?

Comment: You want to execute your handler only if age criteria matches?

Comment: @AbhaySehgal yes

Comment: So, you can use middleware and put your age condition in that middleware if it satisfies call next

Comment: @jakerella its a complex setup , urls are like a/b/c and there are handlers for a/* and i have to intercept a/b/c kind of url and other requests should go to a/*  , so just made a simple example to state my problem

Comment: @AbhaySehgal that is what i was thinking but wanted to know a way through route handlers, thanks a lot for your input

Comment: Probably you should fix your URLs so you don't have this problem in the first place.  In the client, you could put this one age parameter also as a query parameter so you can peek at the query parameter without reading the stream body.

Comment: If your using the typical middleware to read the body, then `req.body` already contains the parsed body and you can just check the parameter there in a request handler before this one and if it's your desired parameter you process it, if not, you call `next()` to continue processing to other route handlers.

Comment: @jfriend00 cant do it , i have stated exactly what i want . The thing is its a very generic api .. and i can change the url

Comment: There is no real difference between middleware and route handlers.  They are basically the same thing so it's kind of silly to be asking to do it with a route handler and not with a middleware.  If you declare the argument `next` and then call `next()`, it will continue routing to other route handlers.  That's how you keep going to other handlers if you don't want to process it yet.

Comment: @jfriend00 whoa .. didnt know that . let me try that one , it makes total sense if that is theoretically possible

Comment: I posted an answer that adds an example of what I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: thanks, will accept , just researching about express a little

Comment: @AbhaySehgal middleware kinda solved my problem , check the comment on accepted answer. i was using app.use . .changing it to app.post solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this sounds like a really bad design so really the better way to fix things is to just fix the URL design so you don't have this conflict between code you can and can't modify.  I say this because it sounds like you're trying to "hack" into something rather than make a proper design.

If your code is using the regular body-parser middleware, then the body of the post will already be parsed and in `req.body`.  So, you can look for the desired parameter in `req.body.age` and check its value.

If it meets your criteria, then you can process the request and you're done.  If it doesn't meet your request, then you call `next()` to continue processing to other request handlers.

```
// make sure this is defined BEFORE other /users request handlers
app.post('/users', function(req, res, next) {
    // test some condition here
    if (+req.body.age > 30) {
        // process the request and send a response
        res.send("You're too old");
    } else {
        // continue processing to other request handlers
        next();
    }
})
```

Comment: any idea why app.use doesnt work and app.post does ?

Comment: @ashishsingh - I'd have to see the overall layout of your code and I'd have to know more about what "doesn't work" means.  `app.use()` is pretty much the same as `app.post()` except that it sees all types of requests, not just POST requests.  But, if you only want to see POST requests, you should be using `app.post()` even for stuff that is more like middleware.

Comment: let me try.. app.post did solve my problem thanks..didnt know that app.METHOD had access to next also that is why i was trying with `app.use` and it was not working

Answer (score 0):

The way I deal with this is if I have a route that works, and I need something else, I add another route that is similar. This way you leave the original alone - which provides a working service. This is what I think you re describing.

You can call routes anything you like. If you want a list of users you can pass a variable like this:

```
  $.get('/contactCard/'+qry);

  app.get('/contactCard/:sort', function(req, res) {
       var cId = req.params.sort;
       console.log('cId: ' + cId);
```

then you set up your search query and go get the data a bit like this:

```
     let params = {
                TableName: ddbTable,
                ProjectionExpression : "cEmail,Forename,Surname",
                KeyConditionExpression: "ID = :e ",
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                    ":e" : cId
                }
            };
     console.log("params", JSON.stringify(params, null, 2));
     docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
```

then you check for error or success:

```
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                } else {
                    console.log("Success", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
                    let contacts = data;
```

then here you render to the page you want and pass the data as you wish.

```
                    res.render('members/contactcard', {  
                                contacts:contacts,
                                static_path: '/static'
                    });
                }
            });
```